# How I can write JPA query for given SQL query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Please suggest how can I write the JPA EntityManager `createQuery` for the given SQL Query:

```
select
    sum(case when Status_2 = 'Allocated' then 1 else 0 end) as Allocated,
    sum(case when Status_2 = 'Bench' then 1 else 0 end) as Bench
    from userbean where Organizational_Unit = 'SIDG Java'
    union   
select
    sum(case when Status_2 = 'Allocated' then 1 else 0 end) as Allocated,
    sum(case when Status_2 = 'Bench' then 1 else 0 end) as Bench
    from userbean where Organizational_Unit = 'SIDG Microsoft'
```

Comment: I wanted provided SQL query which fits into em.createQuery( Answer )

Comment: I mean how I can get JPQL query EntityManager.createQuery(Answer) ...     Provided SQL Query Above

Comment: select bean from userbean bean where bean.organiz =: java or bean.organiz=:microsoft and bean.status_2 =: allocated or bean.status_2. =: bench --> this will return to you list list of size will be your answer , honestly dont understand what you mean

Comment: I mean can you modify SQL given query above into JPQL query EntityManager.createQuery( Answer )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a native sql query with jpa :

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select
    sum(case when Status_2 = 'Allocated' then 1 else 0 end) as Allocated,
    sum(case when Status_2 = 'Bench' then 1 else 0 end) as Bench
    from userbean where Organizational_Unit = 'SIDG Java'
    union   
select
    sum(case when Status_2 = 'Allocated' then 1 else 0 end) as Allocated,
    sum(case when Status_2 = 'Bench' then 1 else 0 end) as Bench
    from userbean where Organizational_Unit = 'SIDG Microsoft'");

List<Object[]> result= q.getResultList();

// for each line retrieved
for (Object[] currentLine : result) {
    System.out.println("Allocated=" + currentLine[0]
                    + ", Bench=" + currentLine[1] ;
}
```

No guarantee but you may test.